# How do I convert a string to a python datetime object with a relevant timezone?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string similar to "2012-06-14 20:38:24.213-7:00" and want to convert it to a python date time object with the time zone kept intact, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A fixed offset is not enough to find out the timezone name.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274743/4279)

Otherwise [`pytz`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) and/or [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil/#head-8d03c6c25ead6f9cab0cde83e6f672b52480ab90) libraries might help:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse('2012-06-14 20:38:24.213-7:00')
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 14, 20, 38, 24, 213000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200))
```